# Transfer element IDs from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I made a small script so that when I click on a button, I can show or hide the description.

```js
    $('.package-1-show').click(function () {
        $('.js-package-1').css('display', 'block');
        $('.package-1-show').css('display', 'none');
        $('.package-1-hide').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.package-1-hide').click(function () {
        $('.js-package-1').css('display', 'none');
        $('.package-1-hide').css('display', 'none');
        $('.package-1-show').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.package-2-show').click(function () {
        $('.js-package-2').css('display', 'block');
        $('.package-2-show').css('display', 'none');
        $('.package-2-hide').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.package-2-hide').click(function () {
        $('.js-package-2').css('display', 'none');
        $('.package-2-hide').css('display', 'none');
        $('.package-2-show').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

```css
#packages-list-1, #packages-list-2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.package-1-show, .package-2-show {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.package-1-hide, .package-2-hide {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.js-package-1, .js-package-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="packages-list-1">
    <div class="name">Package 1</div>
    <div class="package-1-show">View</div>
    <div class="package-1-hide">Hide</div>
    <div class="js-package-1">Package 1 description</div>
</div>

<div id="packages-list-2">
    <div class="name">Package 2</div>
    <div class="package-2-show">View</div>
    <div class="package-2-hide">Hide</div>
    <div class="js-package-2">Package 2 description</div>
</div>
```

But then I want to connect PHP, and my page will look like this

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
    <div id="packages-list-<?= $item->id ?>">
        <div class="name">Package <?= $item->id ?></div>
        <div class="package-<?= $item->id ?>-show">View</div>
        <div class="package-<?= $item->id ?>-hide">Hide</div>
        <div class="js-package-<?= $item->id ?>">Package <?= $item->id ?> description</div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And on the page there can be at least 1, at least 5, at least 10 such elements

But what should I do next with the script? I somehow need to transfer the IDs of the packages to JavaScript so that the script looks something like this

```
        $('.package-' + item_id + '-show').click(function () {
            $('.js-package-' + item_id).css('display', 'block');
            $('.package-' + item_id + '-show').css('display', 'none');
            $('.package-' + item_id + '-hide').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.package-' + item_id + '-hide').click(function () {
            $('.js-package-'+ item_id).css('display', 'none');
            $('.package-' + item_id + '-hide').css('display', 'none');
            $('.package-' + item_id + '-show').css('display', 'block');
        });
```

But how can I transfer the IDs of elements from PHP to JavaScript?

And also, what should I do with the css part, since I also have fixed IDs there?

Comment: This looks like you'd rather need to [delegate the events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/1169519) rather than maintain a complex id system.

Comment: While not elegant, the same way you loop through and output the <div> you can loop through and output the JS.

Comment: Just to be clear: Currently you are not using [the HTML `id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), neither in CSS, nor in JavaScript. You are using classes, which are intended to be more general, not applicable to a single element like ID. The answer is the recommended way to go about this. Rule #1 of programming: Don’t repeat yourself. If several elements behave the same, write the code once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more ways to select and interact with elements than unique identifiers.  In this case you don't want to repeat the same code over and over changing only a number.  Instead, generalize the `click` event handler to work on every set of elements shown.

For any given show/hide link, target the element(s) relative to that link.  For example:

```js
$('.show').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings('.description').css('display', 'block');
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  $(this).siblings('.hide').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.hide').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings('.description').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  $(this).siblings('.show').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
#packages-list-1, #packages-list-2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.show {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.hide {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="packages-list-1">
    <div class="name">Package 1</div>
    <div class="show">View</div>
    <div class="hide">Hide</div>
    <div class="description">Package 1 description</div>
</div>

<div id="packages-list-2">
    <div class="name">Package 2</div>
    <div class="show">View</div>
    <div class="hide">Hide</div>
    <div class="description">Package 2 description</div>
</div>
```

Here I'm specifically using `.siblings()` to target nearby elements relative to the clicked element.  There are a variety of [DOM traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) that can be used to find elements relative to the clicked element.  (For example, a common pattern I've used in more complex markup is to use `.closest()` to traverse to a known common parent and then `.find()` to target element(s) within that overall parent.)

You *might* not even need these parent elements to have identifiers like they do here.  I'm mostly guessing on the balance between generic sets of markup vs. needing to use identifiers in your use case.  That balance can go as far as you like.  But the overall point is to generalize functionality that needs to be applied repeatedly like this so you don't have to copy/paste the same code over and over.

---

If you need to pass values from PHP to JavaScript, you can do that the same way you are doing for HTML. You’ll need a `<script>` element in that HTML:

```php
<script>
$('.js-package-<?= $item->id ?>').css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

The JavaScript in .js files should always stay reusable, and not reference specific IDs.